Why is there no java.util.stream.Stream.toSet() method in Java
There is a java.util.stream.Stream.toList() method in JDK but there is no java.util.stream.Stream.toSet()?
So if I need to convert some stream to List I can use stream().toList() or I can use stream().collect(Collectors.toList()) and if I want to convert some stream to Set I must use stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()).
I'm aware that stream().toList() returns unmodifiableList and stream().collect(Collectors.toList())returns List - I'm just curious why isn't there a toSet method on Stream interface that also return unmodifiableSet?

See the discussion on https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8306888

I imagine it's not a priority as you can achieve the same result using "collect". and "Collectors.toSet()". It's definitely a nice-to-have to shorten your code.

This is a question for JDK developers. Here only invites off topic opinion answers.
